# Объяснить правило написания слова

Tags: общие-вопросы

вот такой заголовок новости: "Утром папа не проснулся". Памяти оставшимся в горах посвящается.

Скажите как правильно: "оставшимся" или "оставшихся"?

И если можно, объясните подробнее, почему так, а не иначе.

Answer (score 2):

Если бы не было слова «памяти», то управление шло бы от глагола «посвящается кому? павшим/оставшимся» (дательный падеж). В данном случае падеж родительный, управление идет от существительного «памяти кого? павших/оставшихся»